# Took serious pay cut for new job, learning NodeJS and ReactJS, how do I approach a new contract (with different company)?

Tags: salary, startup

After 1.5 years focusing on ASP.NET (previously did some C#, PHP, etc over several years), for certain reasons I'm trying a new job (startup, very low wage) and learning NodeJS and ReactJs.

I don't like Javascript but Node and React is so favoured and in-demand (especially outside of large corporations which I don't prefer) so this is a nice opportunity.

I did take a huge pay cut as this current job is a startup-type opportunity which I told the co-founders I'd give them a chance, while we seek funding/ projects etc. However now after a month based on my professional, industry experience and gut feeling it appears likely in 6 months I'd have to look for a 12-month contract and then move country (long-planned move). Yes, I have to accept the risks of my choices, however specifically my question is:

TL;DR: **How do I position myself in 6 month's time when looking for a job that will most likely require NodeJS and ReactJS?** Given my progression over the past say 5+ years through PHP, ASP.NET and now (recent) NodeJS? Will less than 1 year of serious Node + React experience hamper my chances for Node jobs/contracts?

EDIT: Some backstory here regarding considering management but from replies and today's reflection the management thing is a whole 'nother ballgame that I think I should put on the backburner for now. *FWIW: One of the reasons I am in my current situation is I'm looking at the startup scene and non-coding opportunities like project management, product management, perhaps CTO down the line (let's just say I'm not in my 20s). A lot of non-programming 'tech' stuff seems mostly airy-fairy nonsense though, since too much effort is NOT spent on tangible delivery... so I might have to grit my teeth and keep on coding away.*

Thank you for your time and consideration.

**Replies (I can't comment)**
@mutt Yeah cheers it is quite a big divergence and a big risk to get to that level of project management from straight-up coding. Appreciate your answer.

@mawg Cheers, yes the question is a bit muddled as per my current feelings/thoughts. In terms of coding you have clarified that indeed this is the coding progression that's, well, the way things are going. JS has a lot of momentum behind it and C# is seen as "old school". As for management, it's just not my thing for now, that's what I'm finding out (thanks to this current job exposing me to that side of things)... Of course being a mid/senior dev/devops one would organise and lead juniors or other mids, that's fine and I have some experience with interns, juniors, vendors, etc. Normally us devs will have a product and project manager doing the "people and project" stuff.

@mutt @mawg Upon reflection, for the contract, probably something that appeals to me, something that bridges dev and architecture, C# and JS, but definitely more coding oriented. Working with people is more of a "bonus" thing on the resume at this stage, it would appear. If I have another question I'd post it regarding solution architecture or "analyst" type-stuff. But I need to research more on that. Thanks again for the kind replies.

Comment: `TL;DR: How do I position myself in 6 month's time when looking for a job that will most likely require NodeJS and ReactJS? Given my progression over the past say 5+ years through PHP, ASP.NET and now (recent)NodeJS?`. I don't see any problem here. This seems like a normal career progression - for a coder.  You touch on management, but not for your next job, which I find to cloud the question. In fact, it seems like you have two questions - next job & longer term management - and would get better help if you posted two separate questions.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's preferable to integrate edits into your posts instead of just appending them (if they're necessary at all, *to help answer the question*). You should probably also remove the specific technologies from the question, otherwise this it is more asking for specific career advice, which is off topic (although I'm not sure whether this question can be fixed).

Comment: Yes you can comment SaltySub, click on the "Suggest improvement" thing and add your comment :)

Comment: @DarkCygnus Ah interesting that it's under "suggest improvement"... on other Stackexchange sites it's just named "comment". Cheers!

Comment: @SaltySub please refer to this meta post: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5409 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only work with what you have.  I’m not sure of your full history, but it looks like 5ish years which puts you on the low end for management.  Have you led any teams?  If you have any none software development was that in team leadership?  Have you managed accounts or budgets?  Often PMs have a budget along with the project.

You are also missing the design and full sdlc view in your brief description.  SCRUM, KANBAN, Waterfall, etc... experience?  Inter-team dynamics with cross-functional teamwork?  HR, ethics, conflict resolution skills?  Think about a PMP certification if that is the direction you are heading.  BA, QA, Release management, deployment, security are also aspects.

That is plenty to get lost in for years.  I would recommend you find actual jobs you might like in the future and then focus on contracts and roles that give you that experience.  If you want to make it experience and connections are a must and salary comes after.  Naturally you have to make money though so you need to determine your own balance there.

Good luck and if you find a more specific target niche post again with a lot more details for your question.

Comment: On "find actual jobs you might like" ...I think I've neglected to take this basic aspect more seriously and instead trying to be too smart about things. Cheers.